# Windows 7/8 VPN to localhost (one computer only)

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, vpn, remote

In Windows 8.1 (also try windows 7)
I'm trying to create a Windows VPN connection that connects to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
I did all the configuration in the PC (as server) to accept connections, and in the same PC (as client) to connect as a VPN client...
I can establish the first steps of the connection but it fails in the authorization

Already verified the users allowed to connect (in the vpn service)
Already try with assign IP to client from VPN service
Already did all port openning in Firewall (even disabled firewall to test)

...but something fails in the last steps of the connection process...
?any ideas...

Comment: Unless you have a VPN server simply trying to make a VPN connection is going to fail.  You don't indicate what VPN server client you are using

Comment: I think a few more info will help...
I have this sistem working in Windows 2003 server... 
I just can't put it to work in windows 7/8... but i know that the problem must be some minor change in the new Windows Systems...

Comment: Update your question.  If the information is not in the question it can be missed by people.  You don't indicate what your using at the VPN server.

Comment: Why do you need a VPN if you're using `localhost`? Sane loopback implementations don't ever send anything over the actual network; no kind of in-transit encryption is needed for data sent to `localhost`.

Comment: Some more info to the last comments...
I'm using Windows 7 or Windows 8 VPN (Remote and Routing Services).

Comment: Some more info to the last comments...
I'm using Windows 7 or Windows 8 VPN (Remote and Routing Services).
And yes... I'm also using a loopback adapter, put in promiscuous mode, that I'm trying to bridge with the Hyper-V Virtual Switch/es I've already created inside Hyper-V... It's a way to increase security/control of all the connected VM's...

Comment: Similarly, sending data to `localhost` from inside a VM shouldn't attempt to send anything to the host machine.